# From a .txt, how can I get the content of the line above a certain line

Tags: python

I have a .txt file which includes the following:

```
Karin
3543
Joe
2354
Bob
2019
```

I am able to find the maximum value of all integers and have the line in a variable, `i`, but the problem comes in when I try and find the contents of the line above the highest integer. For example, 3543 is the highest, so "Karin" would be stored in a variable. Any idea on how this would be done?

```
with open("r.txt", 'r') as f:
    highestScore = 0
    highestPlayer = ""

    line_numbers = [1, 3, 5]

    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i in line_numbers:
            if int(line) > int(highestScore):
                highestScore = line
            
        elif i > 5: #ammount of lines in .txt file
            break

    
print(highestPlayer, str(highestScore))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way should be a derivate of the York's answer like this (without using pickle or json files):

```
with open('r.txt') as f:
    highestScore = 0
    highestPlayer = ""
    currentPlayer = ""
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i % 2 == 0:  # even line --> player name
             currentPlayer = line
        else:  # odd line --> score
            if int(line) > highestScore:
                highestScore = int(line)
                highestPlayer = currentPlayer.strip()
print(currentPlayer)
```

A shorter way is:

```
with open('r.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
number_per_name = {name.strip():int(number) for name, number in zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2])}
print(max(number_per_name, key=number_per_name.get))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to get consecutive lines from a file lined up horizontally is to use the builtin [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function (this works because the file handles returned by `open` are iterators):

```py
with open("r.txt", "r") as file:
    max_score = float("-inf")
    for player, score in zip(file, file):
        if max_score < (score := int(score)):
            max_player, max_score = player.rstrip(), score
print(max_player, max_score)
```

Answer (score -1):

If the sample text file you described is representative of full text file you might want to  consider keeping track of whether or not the line is even or odd instead of explicitly keeping track of the line numbers where a score is. Then you can record the name on the even line number and then compare the score on the odd line number. If it's larger than the highest score you can overwrite your `highestPlayer` variable and `highestScore` variable.

As an additional note, the final `elif` statement you have there is also unnecessary as the loop will end once it runs out of lines in the text file.

Here's an example trying to keep the code as similar as possible to your current draft.

```
with open("r.txt", 'r') as f:
highestScore = 0
highestPlayer = ""
currentPlayer = ""

for i, line in enumerate(f):
    # Modulo determines if the line number is even or odd
    if i % 2 == 0: 
        currentPlayer = line
    else:
        if int(line) > int(highestScore):
            highestScore = line
            highestPlayer = currentPlayer

print(highestPlayer, str(highestScore))
```